# Can't properly remove docker images from Jenkins using Jenkins pipline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The problem is Jenkins can't remove all images by itself. Sometimes it removes all images, sometimes only part of it, leaving dangling images. At some point it happens by random.

My setup:

- jenkins 2.346.2-jdk11
- docker 20.10.17, build 100c701
- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Some code snippets from Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30'))
        timestamps()
    }
    
    ...build some jar file...

    stages {
        stage("Build docker images") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Bulding docker images"
                        def buildArgs = """\
                            -f Dockerfile \
                            ."""
                        def image = docker.build(
                            "simple-java-maven-app:latest",
                            buildArgs)
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Push to Dockerhub") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Pushing the image to docker hub"
                    def localImage = "${params.Image_Name}:${params.Image_Tag}"
                    def repositoryName = "generaltao725/${localImage}"
                    sh "docker tag ${localImage} ${repositoryName} "
                    ...push to hub...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                echo 'I will always say Hello again!'
                sh "docker rmi -f generaltao725/simple-java-maven-app simple-java-maven-app"
                sh "docker system prune -f"
                sh "docker images"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The full code you is here https://github.com/GeneralTao2/simple-java-maven-app/blob/for_sharing/Jenkinsfile

A snippet from logs:

```
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
21:23:40  I will always say Hello again!
[Pipeline] sh
21:23:41  + docker rmi -f generaltao725/simple-java-maven-app simple-java-maven-app
21:23:41  Untagged: generaltao725/simple-java-maven-app:latest
21:23:41  Untagged: simple-java-maven-app:latest
21:23:41  Deleted: sha256:daffc41b3af93166db4c19d8b4414051b3b4518e6ddd257c748ab6706060ca0d
21:23:41  Deleted: sha256:68b669ea8fdc6f95d9b3804098adc846d08e205f01a5766a9ce9c406a82f41d2
21:23:41  Deleted: sha256:1eafd5ac1d9d3f6e3b578ac0faea1cf6bbda85ab1a2106b590e6a67cc2cfa887
21:23:41  Deleted: sha256:a4f900510305bbd11d46c1b09dabbb03864e46e1b3e9fe4839dbd96a917f6958
21:23:41  Deleted: sha256:f0a6ad878e8be605a4753d9b1aa2d076fcdd3040ddc6d220d60d03e27f4a3864
[Pipeline] sh
21:23:41  + docker system prune -f
21:23:41  Total reclaimed space: 0B
[Pipeline] sh
21:23:42  + docker images
21:23:42  REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
21:23:42  openjdk      11        47a932d998b7   2 months ago   654MB
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
```

What I actually see after `docker images` after pipeline execution:

```
root@470d20ccbca3:/# docker images
REPOSITORY                            TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
generaltao725/simple-java-maven-app   latest    baa11625ecc8   23 hours ago   674MB
<none>                                <none>    2a8333ccbffb   23 hours ago   674MB
```

I am working on it several days, nothing specific about it in the docs... I will be glad for any help!

Comment: Why did the question got down-rated?

Comment: hey your command worked for me, thanks,  docker rmi -f  image_name

Answer (score 0):

The method I wanted to use still doesn't work. But I found a workaround with pretty same affect. You can use `docker exec` from the host side:

```
docker exec jenkins-blueocean /bin/bash -c "docker rmi \$(docker images -q -f dangling=true)"
```

It can be triggered by cron or any web-hook handler. I use [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) and so far it works.